# awk from Python: wrong subprocess arguments?

Tags: python, awk, pattern-matching, subprocess

I need to run the following (working) **command** in **Python**:

```
ip route list dev eth0 | awk ' /^default/ {print $3}'
```

Using `subprocess`, I would have to do the following:

```
first = "ip route list dev eth0"
second = "awk ' /^default/ {print $3}'"
p1 = subprocess.Popen(first.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(second.split(), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Something went wrong with `p2`. I get:

```
>>> awk: cmd. line:1: '
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

What should I do? On a terminal it works perfectly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`split` splits on any whitespace, including that inside single-quoted arguments.  If you really have to, use `shlex.split`:

```
import shlex
p2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(second), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

However it usually makes more sense to specify the commands directly:

```
first = ['ip', 'route', 'list', 'dev', 'eth0']
second = ['awk', ' /^default/ {print $3}']
p1 = subprocess.Popen(first, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(second, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Not the best solution, but while you are waiting for the best answer, you can still do this :

```
cmd = "ip route list dev eth0 | awk ' /^default/ {print $3}'"
p2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: Interesting. I thought I had to split the command like I did above. Is there any difference if, like your example, I don't do it?

Comment: In this example, you don't have to split the command because `shell=True` but that's not safe ([shell injection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments))

Comment: Drop `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`. Also `output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)`